# realloc(): invalid next size:

Tags: c

I'm working on a function that counts the number of occurences of words in a file, I trim the words I find(space delimited), check if they already exist in my string array and if not I expand that array and add the string.

when I try to compile I get the following:

```
In file included from lsa.c:2:0:
read_file.h: In function 'read_file':
read_file.h:57:13: warning: ignoring return value of 'realloc', declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
      realloc(words, (sizeof(char *) * number_of_words));
             ^
```

And when I run:

```
number of words: 1
ELF
number of words: 2
H������H�������ee@b�g�"6,�&@2016-03-04-21.18PID     : 2529                 TID : 140564200679168 PROC : db2sysc 0
PID
number of words: 3
*** Error in `./a.out': realloc(): invalid next size: 0x00000000020b5010 ***
```

at which point I have to press ctrl + c to exit the function, the file I'm giving to the program starts at:
2016-03-04-21.18

there's no ELF or these characters, I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong, probably with my trim function:

```
void trim(char * word)
{
  if(word[strlen(word) -1 ] < 48 || word[strlen(word) -1 ] > 57 //numeric characters
      && word[strlen(word) -1 ] < 65 || word[strlen(word) -1 ] > 90  //uppercase characters
      && word[strlen(word) -1 ] < 97 || word[strlen(word) -1 ] > 122
    )
  {
    word[strlen(word) -1 ] = '\0';
    if(strlen(word) > 0)
      trim(word);
  }
  if(word[0] < 48 || word[0] > 57 //numeric characters
      && word[0] < 65 || word[0] > 90  //uppercase characters
      && word[0] < 97 || word[0] > 122
      )
  {
    memmove(word, word+1, strlen(word));
    if(strlen(word) > 0)
      trim(word);
  }
}
```

I have the following code:

```
#include<string.h>
#include"trim.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

extern char **words;
extern int number_of_words;

void append(char * string,char ch)
{
    int size=strlen(string);
    char temp[size+1];
    strcpy(temp,string);
    temp[size]=ch;
    temp[size+1]='\0';
    strcpy(string,temp);
}

void read_file(char *file_name , int file_number) 
{
  FILE *file = fopen(file_name,"r");
  char line[2048];
  int i = 0;
  char word[64];
  while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) 
  {
    i = 0;
    while (i < strlen(line) && line[i] != '\n' )
    {
      if (line[i] != ' ')
      {
    append(word,line[i]);
      }
      else 
      {
    if (strlen(word) > 1){
      //trim the word
      trim(word);
      //do your magic
      int a = 0;
      int exists = 0;


      while (a < 1)
      {
        if(strcmp(words[a],word) == 0) //word exists in the words array
        {
          exists = 1;
          printf("%s\n",words[a]);
            }
        a++;
      }

          if (exists < 1)
      {
        printf("number of words: %i\n", number_of_words);
        number_of_words++;
        char **temp = realloc(words, (sizeof(char *) * number_of_words));
        if(temp == NULL) {
              //realloc failed.
                  perror("realloc");
                      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                      }
                      words = temp;
        words[number_of_words] = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
        strcpy(words[number_of_words], word);
      }

       printf("%s\n",word);

      memset(word,0,strlen(word));
    }
      }
      i++;
    }

  }
  fclose(file);
}
```

initialization:

```
char **words;
words = malloc(9*sizeof(char *));
  words[0] = malloc(strlen("the"));
  strcpy(words[0],"the");
```

Comment: `man realloc` for the correct usage. It might return a new pointer, but you are ignoring it. Really, read the warning message, it is meaningful.

Comment: just a hint, realloc returns a pointer...

Comment: The compiler gave you a warning.  Why did you ignore it?

Comment: Why are you ignoring the return value of `realloc`? It is that return value that contain the new valid memory pointer. Every time you call `realloc` you should assume that your old pointer value becomes invalid.

Comment: Where is `words` initialized?

Comment: @dbush: Apparently relies on static initialization.

Comment: `if(word[strlen(word) -1 ] < 48 ...` is interesting if `word` is `""`.

Comment: here's words:
char **words;
words = malloc(9*sizeof(char *));
  words[0] = malloc(strlen("the"));
  strcpy(words[0],"the");

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible:
if (strlen(word) > 1){
      //trim the word
      trim(word);

Comment: In what context does your initialization of `word` reside?

Comment: Do you have a word of more than 63 chars?

Comment: `char temp[size+1];` --> `char temp[size+2];`

Comment: ant: not sure what you mean by context
martin: yes
bluepixy: nope that's not it

Comment: size : length of string, +1 : Adds character `1` character, +1:Adds null-character `1` character. total : `size + 2`

Comment: isn't there already a null caracter? in this case we would just be appending a character before the null character(+1)

Comment: The results of `strlen` does not include a null character. e.g result of `strlen("abc")` is `3`

Comment: oh, thank you for explaining that, I'll modify the function, my application is still not working

Comment: Note that not the same as that your application  does not work as a whole and the part of your  questions. We could also be to rewrite the entire correctly, but it is not to be required in this post.

Comment: no, +2 ruins the function and nothing gets appended, this definitely is not right

Comment: `int size=strlen(string);` 3 = strlen("abc")  `char temp[size+1];` char temp[4]; possible index :0,1,2,3.
    `strcpy(temp,string);` temp[0:a],temp[1:b],temp[2:c], temp[3:\0]
    `temp[size]=ch;` temp[3:ch] (rewrite \0) 
    `temp[size+1]='\0';` temp[4:\0] out of bounds. because The secured 4. temp[4] is 5th element.

Comment: `words[number_of_words] = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);` Also out of bounds --> `words[number_of_words-1] = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);`

Answer (score 4):

`realloc` may return a new pointer where more space has been allocated.

```
char **temp = realloc(words, (sizeof(char *) * number_of_words));
if(temp == NULL) {
    //realloc failed.
    perror("realloc");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
words = temp;
```

Comment: Don't blindly clobber the existing pointer with the new one!  If `realloc` fails, you've lost the original pointer and leaked memory.

Comment: If you're just going to exit when the failure happens, memory leaking is irrelevant.

Comment: Yehbut, it's now fairly clear where the "do clever stuff" goes.

Comment: 1. Does the change get rid of the warning? 2. Can you post your modified code too please?

Answer (score 4):

`realloc(words, (sizeof(char *) * number_of_words));`

Be careful of the nuance regarding `realloc`, always use a temporary pointer. If `realloc` fails, the temporary pointer will be `NULL`.

Use this:

```
char **words_temp = realloc(words, sizeof(char*) * number_of_words);
if (words_temp) words = words_temp;
else{
   // Whoops, memory reallocation failure.
}
```

Looking at the initialization as in the amended question:

```
char **words;
words = malloc(9*sizeof(char *));
words[0] = malloc(strlen("the"));
strcpy(words[0],"the");
```

`words[0]` has the supposedly, string 'the', then the following line, copy 'the' into the same pointer location, obviously, OP did not take into account of the terminating string character or NUL, and clobbered the memory pointer contained in the address of `words`.

```
words[0] = malloc(strlen("the") + 1);
strcpy(words[0], "the")
```

Notice the difference? or for sanity, use `strdup` function which takes into account and will add an extra NUL character.

Comment: the +1 made no difference, I'm still getting the same error, I've also tried strdup, same error

Comment: I tried the +1 on the realloc, and it worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

apparently I was not reallocating enough memory, this is my working code:

```
    char **temp = realloc(words, (sizeof(char *) * number_of_words +1));
```